# Node.JS RemoteExec call not firing properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, remote-execution

Querying a database for a list of servers to perform a command on.  The array is populated properly and echos out as planned, but none of the connections occur.  I tried both passing the array directly into rexec and looping through a forEachAsync.  Neither process the server list properly.  Am I referencing the array elements improperly?

Mind the syntax errors at the end, I was just trying to include both methods I tried.

```
#!
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var resultset  = require('node-array');
var rexec = require('remote-exec');
var fs = require('fs');
var _ = require('lodash');
//var streamBuffers = require('stream-buffers');
var moment = require('moment');
var util = require('util');

var now = moment().format('YYYYMMDD_HHmmss');

var logStdout = process.stdout;
var errStderr = process.stderr;

console.log = function () {
  logStdout.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n');
}
console.error = function () {
  errStderr.write(util.format.apply(null, arguments) + '\n');
}

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'abc',
  user     : 'user',
  password : '******',
  database : 'db'
});

var ssh_options = {
  port: 22,
  username: 'e109gh',
  privateKey: fs.readFileSync('R:/nodeJS/sshkey.priv'),
  stdout: fs.createWriteStream('./out.txt'),
  stderr: fs.createWriteStream('./err.txt')
}

var my_conn_options = _.clone(ssh_options);

var cmds = ['hostname -i'];

connection.query('SELECT name FROM server', function(err, rows) {
  rows.forEachAsync(function(element, index, array) {
        console.log(element.name);
                rexec(element.name,cmds,my_conn_options,function(err){
                    if (err) {
                    now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                    console.error(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("it worked for "+element.name);
                    }
                });
        });
});     
//  var buffer = new streamBuffers.WritableStreamBuffer();

connection.end(function(err) {});
//  my_conn_options.stdout = buffer;

//  
//  rexec(rows,cmds,my_conn_options,function(err){
//      if (err) {
//      now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
//      console.error(err);
//      } else {
//      console.log()   
//      }
//  });
//
//});
```

Comment: what do you get as an error in the `console.log` ?

Comment: `{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dev1 dev1:22]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'dev1',
  host: 'dev1',
  port: 22,
  level: 'connection-socket' }`

followed by

`[Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake]`

which makes me think the host string is malformed.  There is no connectivity issues - I can ssh/ping/etc the hosts just fine.